# Find the limit of the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-m(x-x_0)}}$ as $x\to+\infty$ and $x\to-\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Give the limits of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-m(x-x_0)}}$ as $x\to+\infty$ and $x\to-\infty$.

It's a Sigmoid function, so I know to expect integer limits.

To start I set the $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L,$ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Then I used natural logarithm and property of natural logarithms to obtain

$ln(L) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln((1+e^{-m(x-x_0)})^{-1})$.

Following this through I eventually get

$\ln(L) = \lim_{x \to \infty} m(x-x_0)$ And not sure how to proceed/if I have a correct approach.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something obvious, but it appears that $f$ is continuous. So it would be sufficient to take

$$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{1 + e^{-m(x - x_0)}} = \frac{lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 1}{lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 1 + lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{-m(x - x_0)}} = \frac{1}{1 + lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{-m(x - x_0)}}$$

It should be pretty clear that, provided $m > 0$, $e^{-m(x - x_0)} \rightarrow 0$. The same argument could be used for limits at $-\infty$, just yielding the exponential approaching infinity, and thus $f(x)$ approaching $0$.

Comment: Then you could similarly consider arguments for $m < 0$. $m=0$ would be a trivial case and the result not dependent on $x$ at all. Again, not sure if I'm overlooking something though. I don't know much about sigmoids, I'm just looking at what's before me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to go to the logarithm.

If $m>0$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-m(x-x_0)}=0
\qquad
\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{-m(x-x_0)}=\infty
$$
Therefore, for $m>0$,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1
\qquad
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0
$$
The limits are reversed for $m<0$.

For $m=0$ the function is constant: $f(x)=1/2$.